# create UBIFS firmware image with a list of bad blocks?

Tags: firmware, ubifs

I have a router that has two firmware partitions with the same UBI based firmware images inside. They're both damaged because of bad NAND blocks. However I can flash a fresh firmware image using the boot environment. It doesn't help a lot though, because during the flash process I get a a couple of those:

nandflash_block_erase(): Attempt to erase bad nand block XXX

So here's my question: Is it possible to create an UBI image with a list of bad blocks, so that these blocks are essentially not used by the contained UBI volumes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after quite some digging I found the required information myself.

Very simplified spoken, an UBI image doesn't need a "bad block list" or any other information telling it where to find its blocks if some of them have been relocated during flashing due to bad NAND blocks. UBI doesn't even need a specific order for its blocks. This is possible because the UBI driver reads the beginning of all NAND blocks first on initialization to get the required metadata.

There's a few more steps necessary for a proper flashing of UBI images to NAND than just skipping the bad NAND blocks. You can find details [here](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubi.html#L_format).

Because the Broadcom CFE boot environment throws a bunch of "attepted to erase/write bad block" errors during flashing, I have to assume that it is not able to properly write UBI images to NAND flash areas with bad blocks.